# Adam optimizer report error in chainer?

Tags: optimization, chainer

version: chainer 2.0.2
I use Adam optimizer ,then report error, I found it was caused by this code(fix1==0?):
in adam.py:

```
@property
    def lr(self):
        fix1 = 1. - math.pow(self.hyperparam.beta1, self.t)
        fix2 = 1. - math.pow(self.hyperparam.beta2, self.t)
        return self.hyperparam.alpha * math.sqrt(fix2) / fix1
```

error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AU_rcnn/train.py", line 237, in <module>
    main()
  File "AU_rcnn/train.py", line 233, in main
    trainer.run()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 285, in run
    initializer(self)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/extensions/exponential_shift.py", line 48, in initialize
    self._init = getattr(optimizer, self._attr)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/optimizers/adam.py", line 121, in lr
    return self.hyperparam.alpha * math.sqrt(fix2) / fix1
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: What value did you try to change in `exponential_shift`?
Did you know that Adam uses `alpha` as learning rate, and `lr` itself should not be touched.

Comment: How to use adam algorithm? I can't set lr ?

Comment: @corcochann is there any example code how to use adam, yes , I set lr decay exponential_shift in every epoch = 0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "alpha" attribute to control learning rate for `Adam` in Chainer.
"lr" is defined as built-in property, it should not be override by other value.

Set "alpha" as an attribute for `ExponentialShift` ([official doc](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.training.extensions.ExponentialShift.html#chainer.training.extensions.ExponentialShift)) as well to decay learning rate, if you use `Adam` optimizer.

```
from chainer.optimizers import Adam
optimizer = Adam(alpha=0.001)

# --- Define trainer here... ---

trainer.extend(extensions.ExponentialShift("alpha", 0.99, optimizer=optimizer), trigger=(1, 'epoch'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same ploblem, and tried corochann's approach.
However, it didn't slove the ploblem.

---

my chainer version 2.1.0
Used code is https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/cifar/train_cifar.py
be changed L57 into "optimizer = chainer.optimizers.Adam()".

Comment: I think this is a problem of how you import the modules.
But thank you for pointing out, I updated my answer.